# Why the grep result depends on folder path?

Tags: grep, solaris

I meet a strange phenomenom when using `grep` on `Solaris 10`:
I try to use `grep` to find `creat` related `DTrace` probes. When in a folder (`/data1/nan`), it works OK:

```
bash-3.2# pwd
/data1/nan
bash-3.2# dtrace -l | grep creat*
   27 hotspot586         libjvm.so __1cHThreadsJcreate_vm6FpnOJavaVMInitArgs_pb_i_ vm-init-begin
   28 hotspot586         libjvm.so __1cHThreadsJcreate_vm6FpnOJavaVMInitArgs_pb_i_ vm-init-end
  574        fbt              aggr                   aggr_ioc_create entry
  575        fbt              aggr                   aggr_ioc_create return
```

While in another folder(`/data1/nan/DTraceToolkit-0.99/Proc/`), the `grep` can't find anything:

```
bash-3.2# cd /data1/nan/DTraceToolkit-0.99/Proc/
bash-3.2# pwd
/data1/nan/DTraceToolkit-0.99/Proc
bash-3.2# dtrace -l | grep creat*
bash-3.2#
```

Could anyone give any clue about this issue, thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is interpreted by the shell before it reaches `grep`. Quote it:

```
 dtrace -l | grep 'creat*'
```

Comment: :Yes, it worked on both folders. Why the `dtrace -l | grep creat*` can work on a folder while not in the other? I still can't figure out it.

Comment: @NanXiao `creat*` is expanded by the shell (globbing) into the names of files and folders starting with `creat`. Test it out with `echo creat*`.